# How do I add Google AdSense ads to my site

Tags: html, ads, adsense

I created a site with HTML and PHP. I want to add Adsense ads; I inserted the code of for the ad but it does not appear on the site.

I pasted the ad code between the body tags on my page. How can I can fix it?

Comment: Please share your code and the steps that you have followed. Also, sometimes it takes a few hours before ads show up on your website. So check again in a day.

Comment: Did you follow the steps provided on the Google docs API site? https://developers.google.com/adsense/

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create the Google AdSense account and get verified.
Add your site to your dashboard and generate the ad code.

After generating the ad code, Copy and paste the code in the HTML of your site, between the header tags. 
`<head> paste here </head>`

code example

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-745996178687687" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```